# css how to style a select box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've successfully style a select box. However, I have trouble handling the overflow issue. Please see the image.

[image]

Whenever i try too long into the select field, the text cover the dropdown icon(i use an background image for that). 
Anybody know how to make dropdown icon to cover the text if the text field is too long?
I really appreciate it!

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: can you show your current code.

Answer (score 2):

you should first start with a to correct in every browser. then add the padding to let the arrow be alone in the right side. try it.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

and then add your own styles, such as background border, padding, box-shadow and whatever....

good luck!

Comment: FYI, `-moz-appearance: none;` doesn't work in FF. They have that [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985) for years.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `padding`, like:

```
input[type="text"] // Or whatever selector you're using
{
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

So the text doesn't overlap with your background image...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/nekdS/

Comment: it's the select input what the OP is after not text

Comment: No it's not, if you read the question carefully and look at the OP's image, you'll notice is an input with a background image aligned to the right

Comment: @darkajax, it's the `<select>`

Answer (score 2):

easy

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>blabòaablabmalkbmakbvnozeetjztjzrjdjttjtjetjtjetja</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select {
    max-width:200px; /* just my style, edit to what you want */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-image:url('http://pediatrics.evms.edu/assets/images/icon_arrow_down.png'); /* the first icon on google :) replace with your own */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    padding-right:15px; /* this do the trick */
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BdajH/)

Answer (score 0):

Add something like an ID to it then do this:

CSS:

```
#id {
border: 2px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-color: black;
and so on...
}
```